# When does StringBuffer adds strings to the String Pool?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

When I define a `StringBuffer` variable with `new`, this string is not added to the String pool, right?

Now, when I define another `StringBuffer` but not with `new`, I define it as `StrPrev.append("XXX")` suddenly it is.(or so says my college teacher). Why is that? What makes this string to suddenly become a string-pool string?

Comment: All string constants are going into the pool like "XXX"

Comment: StringBuffer never adds to the string pool.  In your question, the literal string "XXX" is recognized by the compiler at compile time and is added to the string pool.

Comment: You are confusing Strings (which may or may not be in the string pool) and `StringBuffer` (which is a way to build strings without having the intermediate result as a string object).

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand. StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer("abcd") -> abcd is not in the string pool. now, StringBuffer str2=str.append("efgh") -> now abcdefgh is the string they both refers to and this string is in the string pool. (by my teacher). Why Is That??

Comment: Your teacher is wrong, or you're misunderstanding.  Whenever you have a string literal -- anything between `"` -- that string goes into the literal pool.  So `"abcd"` and `"efgh"` will both be in the string pool, but `"abcdefgh"` won't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I define a StringBuffer variable with new, this string is not added to the String pool, right?

Creating a `StringBuffer` does not create a `String` at all.

> Now, when I define another StringBuffer but not with new, I define it as StrPrev.append("XXX") suddenly it is.

This is totally confused:

- When you call `strBuff.append("XXX")` you are NOT defining a new `StringBuffer`.  You are updating the existing `StringBuffer` that `strBuff` refers to.  Specifically, you are adding extra characters to the end of the buffer.
- You only get a new `String` from the `StringBuffer` when you call `strBuff.toString()`.
- You only add a `String` to the string pool when you call `intern()` on the `String`.  And that only adds the string to the pool if there is not already an equal string in the pool.
- The String object that represents the literal `"XXX"` is a member of the string pool.  But that happens (i.e. the String is added to the pool) when the class is loaded, not when you execute the `append` call.

(If you teacher told you that StringBuffer puts strings into the Java string pool, he / she is wrong.  But, given your rather garbled description, I suspect that you *actually* misheard or misunderstood what your teacher really said.)

Comment: my teacher said after I define the first StringBuffer and the second, then the text (that was changed) is in the String Pool. is it false?

Comment: If your teacher did say that, it is false.  But I think your teacher did not say that.

Comment: Maybe a pool vs buffer confusion?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - that is a plausible explanation.

Answer (score 1):

"XXX" in `StrPrev.append("XXX")` is a string literal that is interned at class loading time (class loading time of the class that contains the code).

"XXX" is not added to the pool by the `StringBuffer`.

From the [JLS section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class
>   String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings
>   that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned"
>   so as to share unique instances

From the [JLS section 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5):

> Loading of a class or interface that contains a String literal
>   (§3.10.5) may create a new String object to represent that literal.
>   (This might not occur if the same String has previously been interned
>   (§3.10.5).)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your teacher is referring to `XXX` . which goes to StringPool because all string literals written in java program  goes to StringPool while execution...

Comment: downvoter pls care to leave some comment before leaving away from here...Or I consider your this downvote to be mere fun..

Answer (score 0):

`buf.append("XXX")` followed by buf.toString(), and then returning the `string` to the pool. With the pool in place, only one `StringBuffer` object is ever [allocated](http://divnull.com/lward/writing/stringpool.html).